# H2o GBM monotone_constraint parameter for R

Tags: parameters, h2o, gbm

I'm trying to use the new monotone_constraint feature in H2o GBM for R.  There doesn't seem to be any examples, and I don't understand what the documentation provided means when it says

"A mapping representing monotonic constraints. Use +1 to enforce an increasing constraint and -1 to specify a decreasing constraint."

```
gbm_1 <- h2o.gbm(
model_id = "gbm_1"
,x = xvars
,y = yvar
,training_frame = train
,distribution = "bernoulli"
,monotone_constraints = list("var1",1)
)
```

The error i get is 
For input string: "list("var1""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example in Python (which you can read through and understand even if you prefer R), that is linked in to the [docs](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-py/demos/H2O_tutorial_gbm_monotonicity.ipynb). The "mapping" means that you specify which features you want to enforce your monotonicity constraint on, for example:

in python you'd use a dictionary for the mapping: `monotone_constraints = {"MedInc": 1, "AveOccup": -1, "HouseAge": 1}` where the keys correspond to column names.

in R you'd use `monotone_constraints=list('C1'=-1, 'C2'=1)` where `"C1"` and `"C2"` would be the name of your columns.

If you're interested in understanding how the monotonicity constraints are applied see the [blog](https://xiaoxiaowang87.github.io/monotonicity_constraint/) that the docs provide a link to as well.